# detect if page is scrolling for mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

can I detect if a page is currently scrolling in mobile? including momentum scrolling?

basically, I want to run a function but only if there is no scrolling happening at all, like

```
if(!scrolling){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: onscroll = function (){}

Comment: It depends on how the scrolling is taking place.  Are you using jQuery Mobile?  If so, what kind of control are you scrolling?

Comment: I'm not using jquery mobile no

Comment: From the top of my head: You can put an event listener that checks for the offset Top value of a random block on the page, when that offset changes you know it's scrolling.  I bet there's better ways but this one just popped in my head

Comment: You probably don't have to, since mobile browsers block/throttle JS execution during scrolling by themselves. So the reverse of your problem (execute JS during scrolling) is the hard part.

Comment: I'm listening to the touchmove event for my function which seems to be able to fire when scrolling hasn't finished (momentum scrolling, that is)

Answer (score 1):

```
var scrolling = false;
var endScrolling;

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    scrolling = true;
    endScrolling = window.setTimeout(function() {
        scrolling = false;
        window.clearTimeout(endScrolling);
    }, 20);
});
```

Basically what happens here is:

1) when window starts scrolling, "scrolling" is set to true

2) timeout will set the scrolling to false as soon as it's executed, but:

3) Mobile Safari do not execute setTimeout while scrolling (including momentum). Therefore the first execution will occur only as soon as the scrolling really ends.

Comment: From what I've observed `onscroll` event listeners are often triggered after the scrolling has completed, not at start and during scrolling.

Comment: yes, that's true. I always use a library or something to get me going on the mobile part, there's too much fragmentation for global events behaving the same.